# Locate Mails of k9-mail

Tags: k9-mail

Unfortuantely I lost mails on my Desktop and I'm now trying to restore them from my phone. k9-mail shows them all, but I can't find an mbox file or something similar to reimport them into Thundebird.

Does anyone know where exactly k9-mail stores its local mails?

Comment: Is your device rooted? If not, I'd try with an `adb backup` for the k9 package, and then analyze its contents. Mails are most likely stored within the app data directory, my guess would be a database. Cannot check currently, as I'm not at my desk.

Comment: no its not rooted. it worked with adb backup, here's the description (just the first two steps to make it a .tar is enough): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011811
they are not saved as simple mbox files though, it's a SQLite db

Comment: So my guess was correct (and yes, I know that 2-step tar conversion, which is what I had in mind). So then it's a question now on how to extract your mails and convert them into a format Thunderbird can read.

Comment: right. So make it an answer and I can mark this question as solved

Comment: Isn't there a detail missing? I just explained where to find the mails, but not how to make them available in a "standard format". Missing the details for that :) Being at my desk again, I've checked with one of those databases – and couldn't see an easy approach, as a single message is split across multiple tables and columns. So I can put an answer to "where does k9 store its mails", but had to skip on "how to convert them to mbox". Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Well, I can navigate through them with sqlitebrowser. for now thats good and its a technical task to write a script to convert them into an mbox file... Would be glad, of course, if that has been done before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K9 stores mails with its own app data, so you cannot access them without root except through the app. However, you can indirectly get hold on that creating an ADB backup (without password!) and converting that into a tar archive:

```
adb backup -f k9mail.ab com.fsck.k9
ab2tar k9mail.ab
```

`ab2tar` is a small helper script you can find [in the `tools/` directory](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar/tree/master/tools) of my little program [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) (free, open-source; based on Bash and ADB). Alternative approaches for this conversion can also be found at XDA: [What is an android adb backup?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011811).

That done, extract the tarball and navigate into its `apps/com.fsck.k9/db/` directory. Here you will find one or more `.db` files (one per mail account), which are SQLite files you can explore with apps like [SQLiteman](http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/) or [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Mail headers and contents are spread across multiple tables and columns, so I cannot offer you an easy way to convert them into e.g. mbox format. On a "quick duck" (a search with DuckDuckGo) I found that question asked multiple times – but the closest and most precise answer was "you could to that in Python" (of course, without instructions). Still, as requested by you, the first steps as answer: At least you can browse your mails that way using a proper SQLite browser ;)

Comment: I can't backup com.fsck.k9, because it doesn't exist. Is K-9 storing the data now somewhere else? If yes - where?

Comment: I can 'adb shell' into 'data/data' and if I run 'ls' I get permission denied. I can however cd into com.fsck.k9, but how to continue from there on?

Comment: Without root powers, there's not much you can do inside `/data/data`. And if `com.fsck.k9` does not exist, how comes you can "cd into it"? That contradicts each other. Also, no idea why you "cd into" and what you expect to do there: `adb backup` is invoked from a connected computer, not on the Android device.

Comment: That it doesn't exist was my first impression, because even 'adb backup -all' didn't backup that directory. As far as I understood it, adb backup is backing up the data from data/data or isn't it? What's interesting is that I can cd into '/data/data/com.fsck.k9' (which is not included in the tar-file), but I can't do it for packages that are backed up into that tar file.

Comment: Apps can opt-out of ADB backups. In that case, you need root powers to back them up (e.g. with Titanium Backup, or the new root-based backup scripts in Adebar's `tools/` directory. And yes, `/data/data/<packageName>` is one of the things `adb backup` backs up, but not the only. If you study the scripts I've just mentioned you'll see there's more involved.